# Using .NET Standard 2.0 with Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono, .net-standard-2.0

Does anyone know if .NET Standard 2.0.0 is supported on Mono?  I currently have a build that is working fine on windows 10.  When I attempt to use in Mono in a Ubuntu Linux environment I get the following error:

*Could not locate the assembly 'netstandard'.  Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk.*

Dotnet core 2 is added with no problems via the SDK, but I seem to not have any references to .NET Standard 2.  I had a similar problem on windows 10 originally, which was resolved after I updated my version of visual studio.

Answer (score 8):

Consult the [release notes for details](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/), but Mono `5.4.0` includes NuGet 4.3.0 and MSBuild 15.4.

#### Mono 4.8.0 Preliminary support

> API additions for .NET Standard 2.0
>
> We added APIs to comply with .NET Standard 2.0, which is still a work in progress at the time of this writing. Note that in some cases an implementation is still missing and will throw at runtime.

#### Mono 5.2.0 Runtime support (compiling is in "Preview Status")

> .NET Standard 2.0 groundwork
>
> We’ve done all the groundwork to support libraries that conform to .NET Standard 2.0. Loading and running a library compiled against the 2.0 standard should work fine, tooling support (i.e. creating a .NET Standard 2.0 library) is still in preview though.

#### .NET Core 2.0 SDK Installation needed

> You’ll need to install the .NET Core 2.0 SDK for tooling support as we use the MSBuild tasks which are installed as part of the .NET Core 2.0 SDK, similar to how Visual Studio/MSBuild on Windows does it.